# Данные не отправляются на почту

Tags: php

Внутри модального окна форма связи, после ее заполнения, нажимаю кнопку отправить, идет переадресация на send.php, где вместо надписей просто пустая страница, данные с формы на почту не приходят, в чем может быть дело?

HTML:

```html
<form class="form-inline" action="send.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="2" />
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="ИМЯ" name="fio">
  <input class="phone_clear" type="text" id="pwd" placeholder="ТЕЛЕФОН" name="phone" required>
  <button id="submit_desc" class="submit_form" type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
</form>
```

Php:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $to = "antsomov@gmail.com";    
  $from = "info@belswiss-doors.ru"; 
  $fio = $_POST['fio'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $subject = "Заявка с сайта belswiss-doors.ru";


  $mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
  Было отправлено сообщение с сайта! 
  Имя отправителя: $fio
  Номер телефона: $phone
  Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";  

  $headers = "From: $from \r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
  echo "<br /><br /><a href='http://belswiss-doors.ru/'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` а где конкретно на форме элемент с `name="submit"`?, а то лично я такого не вижу.

Comment: точно! прогпустил.. Благодарю вас! Все работает)